# Do you think I'm a bad intern?

Tags: united-states, internship, work-experience

I'm currently doing an unpaid summer internship for graphic design at this small company. Right now, I am more than a month into my internship, but I keep thinking that I'm a bad intern.

I tend to rush through things when I shouldn't be, and that's a habit that I'm trying very hard to fix but not getting fixed fast.

Today I was assigned to change several designs that one of the senior designers created, but I forgot to isolate/detach the designs from the rest of the others, which changed a lot of styles containing those designs. I was rushing, and I didn't know I made such a mistake until the senior designer pointed that out to me. She made the corrections herself, and I think that delayed her getting off work. She told me to be careful next time but I feel so terrible for doing this. I apologized to her, but I didn't know what else to say. I'm just so afraid they'll think I'm sloppy.

I don't think I'm very detailed-oriented as I thought I was. I've been making the same mistakes for a month now, I feel so self-conscious. But really, I enjoy graphic design. And I've learned so much from this internship. But I feel so discouraged.

Other than this, I show up work early, I have never had a sick absence, I socialize with my coworkers, and I don't do things that disrupt anyone.

Comment: The whole point of an internship is learning the lessons you are learning right now :)

Comment: People repeating the same mistakes are usually fired. I recommended to take the necessary time to avoid that.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to workplace.SE! It seems like you are going through a difficult time at your internship. Unfortunately, this forum is not well suited for open discussion - it is for focussed questions with an answer. Please edit your question to focus on a concrete problem - otherwise it will likely be closed. You could e.g. ask "How can I learn to avoid mistakes?", "How can I get feedback from my employer?" or similar...

Comment: I'm sorry, but "what we think" is an opinion-based question. We generally don't handle questions here which ask for personal opinions.

Comment: bad intern?  No, quite the opposite.  As Oscar Wilde said "Experience is merely the name men gave to their mistakes."  You are getting experience, that's what interns are supposed to do

Comment: You might want to read up on [Impostor Syndrome](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11765/ive-somehow-convinced-everyone-that-im-actually-good-at-this-how-to-effect).

Answer (score 13):

Being an intern is all about learning how to function in an actual job, so I wouldn't beat yourself up too much over it. Making mistakes is expected, but you should also learn from them otherwise how are you suppose to grow as an artist and employee?

Most of the time tasks are assigned with a tight deadline so it's admirable that you are trying to get it done fast. What you can do instead is put more emphasis on due diligence and double check your work when you think it's done.

Don't be afraid to ask for advice from your mentor to see if your work is ok, and try to learn from them so that you improve on your next task!

So keep your chin up, keep learning, and do the thing!

Answer (score 3):

As an intern you are expected to make mistakes. Every intern does. But you should learn from these mistakes so they don't happen more than once or twice.

You don't need to rush through. Interns aren't (or shouldn't be) expected to deliver work quickly. Take your time to really understand what you are doing and how that affects other systems/projects/teams. Go slow.